# Columns in the order by list must be unique sql order by

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I am trying to work out bugs on some already created software where I have the following stored procedure:

```
SELECT [ART_NO],[QTY],[DUE_DATE],make=CASE make WHEN 'BANER' THEN 'BANER' Else ' ' + make END, [PRODUCT],[PRICE],[DETAIL],[COLOUR],[RS1],[RS2],[RS3],[RS4],[RS5],[RS6],[RS7],[RS8],[RS9],[RS10],[RS11],[RS12] FROM [DBKular].[dbo].[INVOISTK] where make != '' order by make,  [DUE_Date],[MAKE] asc
```

When I run the query I get the following error: **A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.**

I have been told that this has been working previously so I am unsure as to why this might be occurring, I have tried removing either make or [MAKE]asc but it does not return the data expected. Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your `order by`:

```
order by make, [DUE_Date], [MAKE] asc
```

You have specified `make` twice.  So, this is exactly equivalent to:

```
order by make, [DUE_Date]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not returning the data expected is a logic error, which is not the same problem as a syntax error. You must remove `make` or `[MAKE] asc` from your `order by` so that the query can run. From there, you can address your logic bugs.